# Can not log into OpenWRT web interface with correct password

Tags: authentication, networking, openwrt, luci

I just installed OpenWRT on my Netgear R6120 using the nighthawk firmware update option. Now I am not able to log into the status page of luci. I have used the correct password and it just does not let me to the status page. It will only refresh and show the same authorization site again.

I can however log into the router with ssh and access everything.

Maybe someone can help me? I am looking forward to positive replies

-------------------FIXED-------------------
I just deleted the browser cookies and the cache.

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting cookies is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for not being able to log in, could be that you've disabled HTTP login and you've forgot about it and are trying to log in on http:// ...